# Отправка красивого письма средствами PHP

Tags: php, html

Всем привет! Очередная попытка создать красивое письмо не получилось...
Есть вот такой код, в котором находится шаблон письма

```
$messagetest = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" style="width:100%;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0">
 <head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
...............
Дальше просто стили
...............
<body style="width:100%;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0"> 
  <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
<table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"> 
     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
      <td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-content" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"> 
         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
           <table bgcolor="#6fa8dc" class="es-content-body" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#6FA8DC;width:600px"> 
             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
              <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:20px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px"> 
               <!--[if mso]><table style="width:560px" cellpadding="0"
                            cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:180px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-left" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                  <td class="es-m-p0r es-m-p20b" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:180px"> 
                   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0px"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://hwiiht.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_e7164fb4dd41f045b38a1336f82bb457/images/32621596539945922.jpg" alt style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic" width="180"></td> 
                     </tr> 
и дальше все в таком духе
```

Все тэги закрыты не переживайте. Но при попытке отправить такое письмо, на почту приходит не оформленное письмо, а просто этот код. Что я делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А вы добавляете заголовок, что отправляете html? `Content-type: text/html;`

Comment: А куда его добавлять?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php параметр `additional_headers`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас почитаю. Просто никогда раньше не сталкивался

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не пыхо-разраб, но хранить `html` в коде это плохо. Храните его в файлах `.html`, а их просто подключайте.

Comment: А вот еще вопрос. Раньше у меня значения переменных передавались в текст и в сообщении было то, что введено в форме, а теперь переменная просто отображается как $name и т.п. Как мне это исправить?